# To use implemented methods in the tests are good or bad idea?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I am testing a method, that in some cases return a new object and in some cases returns an existing object but updated.

I have a method that creates a new object in a default state, so i am wondering if it would be a good idea to use this method in the tests of the new method to check if it is a new object or not, so I could reuse code and not check all the properties one by one, because I can use another method to compare both objects.

But I have doubts about if it is a good idea to use this kind of methods in the tests.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't sound very "unit" to me. Consider reworking your tests. It sounds like you are testing more than you should.

Comment: We tend to start off with extremely granular tests and then gradually move toward testing functionality. If the first method is a) tested and b) extremely simple, then using it as a step in a test is okay. The possible catch is that the tests you write aren't testing the first method, but they do depend on it. That means your tests are coupled to your production code. But that's true of most tests we write. It's awesome if we can figure out how not to do that, but most of the time we're ahead of the game if we're just writing testable code and unit tests.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/10/03/TestContravariance.html). I wish I could say that I'm writing tests on this level. I've asked people to express their thoughts on this. They tend to say that they understand it and then use examples which indicate that they don't. I take it as meaning that there's plenty of room to learn and grow. Perhaps we used to write untestable, untested code. Now we get all sorts of benefits from writing unit tests. That's a huge win. This just means that, like always, there's yet another level.

Comment: You could do that. But what happens if "a method that creates a new object in a default state" has a bug?  If method under tests uses the same "a method that creates a new object in a default state" to create a new object that is returned and then you assert against an object that is created by the same method - you missed a bug.  If this is not the case, than it should be ok

Comment: If you a test that verifies the method creating a default object, it also should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to use a helper class or factory to generate and test objects in unit tests to increase maintainability of code. (by having less of it)